# Change godep to a previous version

Tags: go, godeps

I am trying to revert my godep to a previous version. I need v52 but go installed the latest v74 when I ran go get godep.

I tried replacing the godep binary in $GOPATH/bin. And go is picking it up.

But the problem is when I try to run godep like `godep restore` or anything I get errors like below. I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
godep: Dep (github.com/BurntSushi/toml) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bufio) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/armon/go-metrics) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bufio) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (io) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/private/endpoints) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (fmt) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/private/protocol) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (crypto/rand) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/private/signer/v4) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (crypto/hmac) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/private/waiter) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (fmt) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/elasticache) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (time) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bufio) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/garyburd/redigo/internal) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (strings) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bufio) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/go-ini/ini) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bufio) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/go-stack/stack) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/inconshreveable/log15) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (net/http) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/martini-contrib/cors) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (net/http) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/mattn/go-colorable) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/mattn/go-isatty) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (syscall) not found
godep: Dep (github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (crypto/md5) not found
godep: Dep (golang.org/x/net/context) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (errors) not found
godep: Dep (golang.org/x/sys/unix) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (errors) not found
godep: Dep (golang.org/x/text/transform) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (bytes) not found
godep: Dep (golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm) restored, but was unable to load it with error:
    Package (fmt) not found
godep: Error checking some deps.
```